# How to add public virtual host in Apache 2.4 with WAMP

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, wampserver

> I have an Apache server that handles two virtual host on port 8080, one is private (localhost) and a second one is public (internet). The private virtual host works fine but the public keeps redirecting all public requests to the localhost and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help! Below is the `httpd-vhost.conf` file:

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/App
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/App/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
#
```

> Also, this is running WAMP / Magento on Windows Server 2012 and hosted in Azure. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the virtual host was configured correctly and the re-directing problem was in MySQL Magento Db, which was pointing to the `localhost:8080`. I changed `core_config_data` under `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`  to my public domain and it worked fine. I posted this answer in case someone else lands here with a similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find the comments on virtual host settings.

```
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
```

[Refer this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)